# How to set ANT_HOME in Jenkins in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ant, jenkins

I am new to Ubuntu.I have installed ant using `apt-get install ant` then I tried `which ant` which showed the path `/usr/bin/ant` I included the same path in Jenkins ANT_HOME  but it shows `/usr/bin/ant` is not a directory.I tried adding the ANT_HOME in .bashrc file .what should I need to do to set the ANT_HOME in Jenkins.Please help

Comment: Why do you not install ant threw jenkins? You can than use different versions of ant simultaneously.

Comment: Previously while working in windows I came across some problem with automatic installation that's why I preferred manually configuring ant

Comment: Ok. Look in /usr/share/ant. When this exists, then ANT_HOME should point to this location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins can use its own versions of Ant, and this is really the preferred way. You can have multiple versions of Ant in Jenkins, and each job can use whatever version you desire.

Go to the Configuration Section (`$JENKINS_SERVER/jenkins/configure`). Look for the *Ant* section, and click on the *Ant Installation* button. To add an Ant installation, click on *Add Ant*, then add in a name which should include the Ant version. Click on the *Install Automatically* button, and under the *Install from Apache*, select the version you want to install.

Once this is done, you will get a choice of Ant installations when you select that you want to do an *Ant Build* when you configure a job.

Using the default Ant version can be tricky if it is updated, and your job can't use the newer version. Or, if someone adds something to the default Ant version that breaks your builds.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you should install ANT through jenkins itself, which allows multiple versions without polluting the actual jenkins machine environment. But if you must...

> I tried which `ant which` showed the path `/usr/bin/ant` I included the same path in Jenkins `ANT_HOME` but it shows `/usr/bin/ant` is not a directory.

`which ant` shows the path **and** executable. Your error is 100% correct and expected: `/usr/bin/ant` is **not** a directory. `/usr/bin/` is the path to the directory and `ant` is the executable.

Comment: This is not correct. `/usr/bin` is not `ANT_HOME` but instead the location of a symlink to its executable. `ANT_HOME` must point to the location where Ant was installed. `ANT_HOME` is most likely `/usr/share/ant` if installed using `apt-get`.

Comment: @danpayne17 what is not correct? Where did I say anything about ANT_HOME?

Answer (score -3):

try
    export ANT_HOME=/usr/bin/ant
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.025
    export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${ANT_HOME}/bin